# No JSON object could be decoded. Valid Json

Tags: python, json, sockets

I have a weird problem

I have a program which sends a json string through a socket:

```
json_string = JSONEncoder().encode({
    "id_movil": str(id_movil),
    "correo": "is_gom@live.com.mx"
})

socket_client.sendall(json_string)
```

On the server I have:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
buffer_json = conn.recv(1024)
data = json.loads(buffer_json)
```

Then, an exception is thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

    data = json.loads(buffer_json)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

When I change the value of "correo" in json from `"is_gom@live.com.mx"` to `is_goma@live.com.mx` or any other string the exception is no longer thrown.

PS. The exception is only thrown when I use sockets. When I use `json.loads` on python shell it works

Comment: Is the data returned by `conn.recv` the same as that passed to `socket_client.sendall`?  Did you check?

Comment: Yes, is the same. For being precise, this: {"correo": "is_gom@live.com.mx", "id_movil": "15"}

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't see anything wrong with the parts of code you've posted, so I took the liberty of recreating missing bits as I see them fit.

Server:

```
import json
import socket

host, port = "127.0.0.1", 9696

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
buffer_json = conn.recv(1024)
data = json.loads(buffer_json)
print(data)
```

Client:

```
import json
import socket

id_movil = 5

json_string = json.JSONEncoder().encode({
    "id_movil": str(id_movil),
        "correo": "is_gom@live.com.mx"
        })

socket_client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket_client.connect(("127.0.0.1",9696))
socket_client.sendall(json_string)
```

And when I run it, it runs just fine. So your issue is either with network fragmenting the data, so it is not coming through in one go (unlikely given the size of data, but possible), or in the pieces of code you didn't show us.
If it's the former, then you will have to loop over conn.recv() until all of the data went through.

Comment: But, if it was the network fragmenting the data, then putting a bigger string shouldn't come in one go, and it happens.

Comment: @imarban Then the error is in code you've decided to not share with us.

Comment: Also, I'm receiving the same I send

Comment: Actually I'm testing the code I posted isolated, I guess is a encoding problem, but I don't know

Comment: If you run non-utf8 terminal, possible. And that would be a good time to move to python3 which has proper mechanisms to tackle the pesky encoding.